Is there any reason not to use a 7805? Assuming I need a linear reg and I've got the headroom
I know this part is positively ancient, but I'm not aware of any reason not to just keep using it. Do modern parts offer any advantages? I don't need low quiescent current, or a low dropout voltage.
I'm using it to create a low noise rail for some op amps on a motor driver board.

One factor is that it depends on the source being regulated. The LM78XX series has a PSRR which has a peak at ~100Hz. This means it was originally designed to regulate a full wave bridge rectifier output from 50Hz or 60Hz AC systems. Other linear regulators may have PSRRs that peak at different frequencies, possibly at the switching frequency of a DC-DC converter which precedes this regulator or at the frequency of high current peaks in your load.

"Motor" could mean anything. The frequency and current draw of the motor will matter a lot.

"Ancient" isn't necessarily a bad thing - if something works well, there's no need to abandon it.

I guess you already know, but for completeness I will mention that a drawback to a linear regulator is that it may dissipate a lot of power: The voltage dropped * the current output = internal dissipation.
So for example a 7805 with a 12V supply outputting 0.5A dissipates: (12V-5V)*0.5A = 3.5W

@Frodyne And the waste heat keeps my board nice and dry

There are many brands of 7805, and a lot of them don't publish much useful data, so who knows what you'll get.
However, TI does post PSRR and output impedance vs frequency in the datasheet. If you don't mind the high dropout and high idle current, 78xx series regulators offer pretty decent performance, with much better PSRR and transient response than pretty much all modern micropower LDOs and some non-micropower ones too. It's much easier to make a fast high PSRR regulator with a follower output (high dropout) than a common emitter output (low dropout).
When using 7805 you should stay within the "historical context" so to speak, it likes a large-ish aluminium output cap, so board real estate is another drawback.
Some notes:

PSRR at 120Hz is useless in your case since you're probably going to PWM that motor at a much higher frequency and have plenty of ripple at the PWM frequency on your power rail. So having a PSRR vs frequency plot in the datasheet is important.

"Low Noise" regulators and power rails can only exist if the load draws constant current. If the load draws varying current, then the rail will fluctuate according to the transient response of the regulator, so a fast regulator may end up having lower pk-pk variation than a "low noise" one.

On a motor control board, the most important is PSRR and putting the "0V reference" of the regulator (ie, GND) at a quiet place in the layout, because it will output "GND" plus its nominal output voltage, so if "GND" is noisy, it will reproduce all the noise in the output.

Regulators and opamps lose PSRR at high frequency, so a simple LC filter can be a good complement.



It likes a large-ish aluminium radiator as well.

There's no real reason not to use them if all the relevant characteristics work for you. They've been around for a very long time and will continue to be available for a very long time. They're relatively cheap and widely mutiple-sourced. They're more stable (against oscillatory behavior) than most more modern regulators (stable for any capacitive loading and regardless of capacitance ESR, and with no current load if the input voltage is not too high). However we seldom need 1A capability in a linear regulator unless there's some need for brief pulses of high current.
So I would rather use the 78M05. It's generally significantly cheaper (may vary depending on where and from who you buy them) and has similar characteristics for loads up to hundreds of mA and is also multiple sourced. The 78L05, on the other hand, has quite different (and not as good) characteristics.

You're making a "low noise rail" on a motor board so PSRR is probably going to be an important figure for you to consider. 78xx is 70-ish dB which is still fairly competitive.  As @Neil_UK mentioned, you can find higher but maybe 70 is fine.
Some of the newer regulators are stable without external caps which can cut down on your solution BOM and real estate but I'm guessing you'll probably want some sort of cap on the rail so this is probably not a selling point for you.

There is not enough details to say if a 7805 will do or not in your case.
Feel free to use it, but lower noise alternatives may exist.

In what way do the alternatives reduce noise?

@Drew there may be parts that are designed to have a lower noise. But check the other specifications as well, PSRR, line regulation, load regulation are the main ones. Are any of these important in your application?

@Drew All semiconductors are noisy. Newer semiconductors are made with more modern technology and circuitry and are better than decades old design, even if the decades old design is still made with more modern processes. The 7805 cound have 150 microvolts RMS noise while an ultralow noise regulator may have less than 1 microvolts RMS. A factor more than 2 decades better.
